# Insert into temporary table from select returns blank table

Tags: t-sql, split, temp-tables

I'm trying to fill two temporary tables with ids coming from outside as a single string that I split and save to a third temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempProdotti (Id int NULL);
CREATE TABLE #TempProdottiAggregati (Id int NULL);
CREATE TABLE #TempCorsiSingoli (Id int NULL);

-- split ids and cast them as INT
INSERT INTO #TempProdotti (Id)
(SELECT CAST(value AS int) AS Id
 FROM string_split('3116,3122,3090', ','));

-- then search into products table if the ids match any aggregated (or not) product.
-- then save aggegated products id in one table and the not aggregated ones into another

INSERT INTO #TempCorsiSingoli (Id)
(SELECT Id
 FROM mod_SHOP_Prodotti
 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #TempProdotti)
   AND ProdottoAggregato = 0);

INSERT INTO #TempProdottiAggregati (Id)
(SELECT Id
 FROM mod_SHOP_Prodotti
 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #TempProdotti)
   AND ProdottoAggregato = 1);



SELECT *
FROM #TempProdotti;
SELECT *
FROM #TempProdottiAggregati;
SELECT *
FROM #TempCorsiSingoli;

DROP TABLE #TempProdotti;
DROP TABLE #TempProdottiAggregati;
DROP TABLE #TempCorsiSingoli;
```

When I run the query, if it doesn't find anything in one of the two temporary tables, it just returns an empty table:
[image: sql]

Is there a clean way to return `NULL` on Id in case the condition is not met?

Comment: FYI, there's no need to wrap your `SELECT` statements in parenthesis like that, it actually makes them a little confusing to read as it makes them look like subqueries.

Comment: So are you expecting to `INSERT` the value `NULL` into the table if there are no rows returned from the query? Or are you looking to return the value `NULL` in your latter `SELECT`s if there's no rows in the temporary table?

Comment: @Larnu exactly the second.
I would need to split the ids inserted in the "main" into two temporary ones, and possibly return null if one of the two queries has no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to `LEFT JOIN` from a data set with row of `NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT TP.*
FROM (VALUES(NULL))V(N)
     LEFT JOIN #TempProdotti TP ON 1 = 1;
```

If `#TempProdotti` contains rows, then the data in the table will be returned. If not a single row, of `NULL`s will be returned.

---

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TempProdotti (Id int NULL);
CREATE TABLE #TempProdottiAggregati (Id int NULL);
CREATE TABLE #TempCorsiSingoli (Id int NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO #TempProdotti (Id)
SELECT CAST(value AS int) AS Id
FROM string_split('3116,3122,3090', ',');

INSERT INTO #TempCorsiSingoli (Id)
SELECT Id
FROM mod_SHOP_Prodotti
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #TempProdotti)
  AND ProdottoAggregato = 0;

INSERT INTO #TempProdottiAggregati (Id)
SELECT Id
FROM mod_SHOP_Prodotti
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM #TempProdotti)
  AND ProdottoAggregato = 1;

GO

SELECT TP.*
FROM (VALUES (NULL)) V (N)
     LEFT JOIN #TempProdotti TP ON 1 = 1;
SELECT TPA.*
FROM (VALUES (NULL)) V (N)
     LEFT JOIN #TempProdottiAggregati TPA ON 1 = 1;
SELECT TCS.*
FROM (VALUES (NULL)) V (N)
     LEFT JOIN #TempCorsiSingoli TCS ON 1 = 1;
GO
DROP TABLE #TempProdotti;
DROP TABLE #TempProdottiAggregati;
DROP TABLE #TempCorsiSingoli;
```